# when I write npm install -D tailwindcss in my vscode terminal then it shows " npm EER! code ERESOLVE"

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

npm install -D tailwindcss

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving:
> react-google-login@5.2.2
> npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @react-oauth/google@0.2.8
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-oauth/google
> npm ERR!     @react-oauth/google@"^0.2.6" from the root project
> npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.1.6
> npm ERR!   node_modules/next
> npm ERR!     next@"12.1.6" from the root project
> npm ERR!     peer next@">=10.2.0" from eslint-config-next@12.1.6
> npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-next
> npm ERR!       dev eslint-config-next@"12.1.6" from
> the root project
> npm ERR!   6 more (react-dom, react-icons, styled-jsx, ...)
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
> npm ERR!   react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer
> dependency: react@17.0.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
> npm ERR!   node_modules/react-google-login
> npm ERR!     react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream
> dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\visitor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for
> a full report.

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm ERR!     C:\Users\visitor\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-28T06_41_44_897Z-debug-0.log

I was expecting that Tailwind css to be installed

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it using the legacy peer dependencies flag.

npm install -D tailwindcss --legacy-peer-deps